# Way to disable checkstyle check for the license in the source code

Tags: java, maven, plugins, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I am injecting checkstyle maven [plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/index.html) in my Java project. And I have one problem. The problem is that the plugin checks for a style license, which is placed inside the source code file.

What gives me an error:

```bash
[ERROR] src/main/java/io/github/eocqrs/kafka/consumer/KfConsumer.java:[11] (sizes) 
LineLength: Line is longer than 80 characters (found 81).
```

How do I turn off the license block check?

Comment: You can provide a suppression XML file with the classes and line number ranges to be ignored. More here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/suppressions-filter.html

Comment: @Mar-Z is not what I am looking for. In the case you provided, I would have to describe every file in my project, which is completely unacceptable.

Comment: It's not the licence check it's a check for the line length... you have to configer it appropriately...

Comment: @khmarbaise it is obvious that the string length is checked, I just need to turn off the all checks for the license section

Comment: @IvanIvanchuk You do not need to describe every file in your project.  A Checkstyle suppression file takes a regular expression for the files it is expected to apply to.  Also, the LineLength check itself can be told to ignore lines matching a designated regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found a solution, not without the help of comments.

The first thing I had to do was to determine which block I needed to exclude for the test. In my case it was from line 0 to line 23. Then I had to create a file `checkstyle-suppressions.xml` which would look like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC "-//Checkstyle//DTD SuppressionFilter Configuration 1.0//EN" "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/suppressions_1_0.dtd">
<suppressions>
  <suppress checks="LineLength" files=".*\.java$" lines="0-23"/>
  ...
</suppressions>
```

In it I've listed all the checks I wanted to exclude for the license block. Also to check only Java sources I specified with regex file type - `.*\.java$`.

Next, in project `pom.xml`

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>verify-style</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <suppressionsFileExpression>checkstyle.suppressions.file</suppressionsFileExpression>
              <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

I specified the `suppressionsLocation` configuration file I needed and the required `suppressionsFileExpression` setting